# Dynamically Transposing/Pivoting SQL Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I'm sorry to ask this question since there are so many for this topic, but I've been looking around the general Pivot questions a lot without finding a solution because of an added dimension I'm dealing with, and I can't get my head around it.
To determine the "experience" of crews when they race together (this was the simplest illustration of what I have to deal with) I need to find out for a given race what previous races any part of the crew has taken part in - in a user-friendly form, of course.
If you don't want to read through the structure, here's [the SQL Fiddle Shortcut](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6183/1/0)
I have contacts, cars and races as simple entitites. Then there are Entries to tie cars into races. And Crews, consisting of contacts in a given car of a race.

Now, for a given entry (aka for a given car in a given race) I need to find all previous races that car took part in and compare which of the current crew might had taken part in it.

For example, for Entry ID 5 (== "Fast Car" in Race "Current Race") I need to list the crew and make X marks if they had also been in any previous races (== Race ID < the ID to check) in the same car "Fast Car".

The end result I'm looking for is this - although the "Current Race" column would be superflous since this is the starting point for checking anyway.

```
                Current Race | Old Race | Even Older Race
Gladys Friday       X             X            X
Mandy Lifeboats     X             X            X
Justin Case         X       
Candy Barr          X       
Harvey Theryet      X             X            X
```

It'd be great if you could help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a dynamic query that will 'adapt' to whatever races the result is gonna have. Here's an example wich gives the *same result as your example:

```
DECLARE @entry INT, @race INT, @car INT, @races VARCHAR(8000), @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @entry = 5

--SAVE THE RACE ID AND CAR ID OF THE SPECIFIED ENTRY
SELECT @race = Races_ID, @car = Cars_ID
FROM dbo.Entries
WHERE ID = @entry

--SELECT THE RACES WITH THE SAME CAR WHERE THE CREW MEMBERS OF THE SPECIFIED ENTRY HAVE PARTICIPATED BEFORE
SELECT cr.ID, cr.contactname, r.ID raceid, r.racename
INTO #Exp
FROM dbo.Contacts cr
INNER JOIN dbo.Crews cs
ON cr.ID = cs.Contacts_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Entries e
ON cs.Entries_ID = e.ID AND e.Races_ID <= @race AND e.Cars_ID = @car
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Races r
ON e.Races_ID = r.ID
ORDER BY cr.ID, r.ID DESC

--CREATE THE DINAMIC LIST OF COLUMNS (RACE NAMES) WE'RE GOING TO USE IN THE PIVOT
SELECT @races = ISNULL(@races + ',[', '[') + r.racename + ']'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT raceid, racename FROM #Exp) r
ORDER BY r.raceid DESC

--GENERATE AND EXECUTE THE DYNAMIC QUERY
SET @query = 
'SELECT contactname,' + @races +
'FROM (SELECT ID contact_id, ID, contactname, racename FROM #Exp) p
PIVOT
(COUNT(ID) FOR p.racename IN ( ' + @races + ' )) as pvt
ORDER BY contact_id'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query

DROP TABLE #Exp
```

This will generate a table with 1's and 0's specifying in wich previous races the crew members of the specified entry have been. It doesn't matter wich and how many races there are, as the dynamic query will adapt to show them all.

**the result this query has considers the races with the same car as the specified entry; the example you put has Mandy Lifeboats on Old Race wich was with another car. Maybe I misunderstood the question or it really was confusing?*

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the answer - I'll need a little while to understand and adapt this. Re your question: It is well possible this is a bit confusing; my attempt to create an easier to understand example might have made it more difficult, really...

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'll mark this as answer. It still looks as though there must be a slightly better way to combine this into a query or CTE to make it applyable on a number of entries, and it is a bit slow when working with a few thousand records. But just coming up with a proper example is a challenge in itself... I understood the pivot basics now, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Contact can only appear once per race, doing a COUNT on race name would produce a binary table of when a person appears in a race or not.  If for some reason the same person can be in the same race multiple times, then you'll just get a number greater than 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ContactName, RaceName FROM [dbo].[Entries] AS e 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Races] AS r ON [e].[Races_ID] = r.[ID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Cars] AS c ON e.[Cars_ID] = c.[ID]
    LEFT JOIN Crews ON e.ID = Crews.Entries_ID
    LEFT JOIN Contacts ON [Contacts].[ID] = Crews.Contacts_ID
) src
PIVOT (
    COUNT(RaceName)
    FOR RaceName IN ([Current Race], [Old Race], [Even Older Race])
) pvt
```

Comment: Thank you - please don't think the lack of an immediate accept means I'm not interested, I simply need some time digesting this for the real-world application. I'll report back soon